# Honeycomb makes texts pixelized

Tags: android, android-layout, rendering, android-3.0-honeycomb

My app looks fine on my Galaxy S, but when I run it on a Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 3.0), the texts look pixelized/smeared:

[image]

The XML used for the Synchronize button follows:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/synchronizeButton"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="Synchronize"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/buttoncolors"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

Is there something wrong I am doing, or is there something special I need to do to make my apps Honeycomb-compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your application running in compatibility mode? If so, this is expected. You need to indicate in your manifest that you support large screens.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Somehow I thought it would happen automatically... Will have to redo my layout now :)

Answer (score -1):

Try changing textSize="20dp" to textSize="20sp".  When dealing with text you should always use "sp" (scale-independent pixel).  Hopefully this fixes it.

see this page for more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: While this is usually sound advice, this is not the issue here. Using dip vs sp would not affect text rendering this way.